# I have too much oil going into my intake air filter. What could be causing it for the 2003 Nissan Altima

Tags: nissan, altima

Nissan Altima 2003 oil is going into air intake filter area.

Comment: If it has a turbo then it's probably it, although it shouldn't be on the filter but after the turbo.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked your PCV system?